# Django Button Behavior within View that Handles POST and GET Requests

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've implemented the code on the site at the link below. I'm trying to understand what is happening with the log_message view. I understand that the view below handles both POST and GET requests. Note, in the template that this log_message calls (log_message.html), there is a form string/char field called message and a button to log the message.

[Django and VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django)

So, on the first call to this view (view.log_message), the first if is passed and the render function is called where it passes the form to the template. The template contains a message field and log button. I insert some text into the message form, and then press the log button. While doing this in VSCode debugger, i notice that when i press the log button, the control is sent back to the start of the log_message function, but this time request.method=='POST'. There seems to be some underlying behavior that when the button is pressed it reloads the page and thus calls the log_message view again? But that doesn't seem very transparent in the code.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
def log_message(request):
    form = LogMessageForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.save(commit=False)
            message.log_date = datetime.now()
            message.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        return render(request, "dashboard/log_message.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: *There seems to be some underlying behavior that when the button is pressed it reloads the page* - Becouse when you click button it sends **POST** request with data and saves that data and redirects you on same page.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this:

```
    def log_message(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LogMessageForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                message = form.save(commit=False)
                message.log_date = datetime.now()
                message.save()
                return redirect("home")
        else:
            form = LogMessageForm()
        return render(request, "dashboard/log_message.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: You can check in django page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Add some comments to explain your code, will be helpful for others to understand